# How much difference in the Akaike Information Criterion is reasonable between a Spatial and a Non spatial Model

Tags: least-squares, aic, stepwise-regression, variogram

I am doing supervised land value modelling (900 observations) and I am comparing two approaches to do a variable selection (51 variables). I am using R. The first one is a backward step-wise regression using OLS fitting and evaluating the differences in the Akaike Information Criterion (AIC). The difference in the second one is that I am modelling the spatial dependence using an exponential variogram fitted to the residuals via Maximum Likelihood (geoR Package). As a first step when comparing the spatial and non-spatial models containing all the 51 variables the AIC goes from +180 (non spatial, 52 parameters) down to -57 (spatial, 54 parameters). A difference of 237 AIC points. Now, this is a huge improvement but I got the comment that it might be a bit suspicious.
     1) question: I see this difference as a mere improvement as a consequence of addressing the spatial structure of the residuals. Should I be suspicious about this big difference in the AIC, more than 200 points going from positive to a negative value?

Furthermore, when doing the step wise regressions I noticed that one variable seems to unexpectedly have tremendous importance in the model, showing an increase of more than 300 AIC points in the spatial model when removed (from -57 to +377). Its a variable that tells in which point of time the observation was done (from year 2008-2014). Now this is obviously suspicious, given that the goodness of fit in terms of R2 only decreases from .80 to .75. I got advised to treat this variable separately by either omitting it, or  running first a model only with this variable, and then use the residuals to select the rest of the variables.
    2) question: Can you please share your piece of advice on this case?